# cor function in R producing NAs

Tags: r

I'm looking at the correlation of a very large matrix using R's cor function, and was wondering if there was a way to prevent the cor() function in R producing NA values for variables that are perfectly correlated, Is there a command to have it produce a 1 value instead of NA? . 
I want to pass the correlation matrix to the findCorrelation function in the caret package to remove highly correlated variables.

Comment: Do you have missing values in your matrix?

Comment: No there are no missing values, some 0's but no NAs

Comment: You should check whether you matrix is numeric.

Comment: There's a mixture of integer and numeric values, I'll try putting an as.numeric() wrapper around the data frame.

Comment: Please identify 2 columns returning `NA`.

Comment: I've found a column in my data comprised of 0's only, is there a way to omit these when calling cor?.

Comment: If you first remove columns filled with 0 (or any constant), probably.